# With nmap it is possible to scan according mac address?

Tags: nmap

I would like to know if it's possible to use nmap in order to scan hosts according to their mac adress.

Or if it's not possible to do it direclty, is there an option (i didn't find) to select only hosts with a specific mac adress ?

Cheers

Comment: This question is not about programming, and thus is off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Ok, but could you suggest me another forum to ask questions about security ? I can't find one

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thank you